# The server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) problem

Tags: reactjs, api, http-status-code-404, mern

I'm facing a 404 issue in my project.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I can't figure out where is the problem coming from. I a newbie to MERN stack. How can I resolve this issue?

This is my POST API

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const _id = await getNextSequence("courier")
    req.body.id = _id    
    
    const courier = new CourierInfo(req.body)
    await courier.save()
    res.sendStatus(200)
  } catch (error) {
    
    res.sendStatus(500)
  }
})
```

This is create method of the frontend.

```
// create method
  const submit = async (e, { resetForm }) => {       
      try {
        setCallingBackend(true)
        await axios.post('/courier', e)
        resetForm()
        setAlert({
          showAlert: true,
          severity: 'success',
          message: 'Courier information created successfully!',
        })
      } catch (error) {
        if (error.response.status === 422) {
          setAlert({
            showAlert: true,
            severity: 'error',
            message: 'Courier information already exists!',
          })
        } else {
          console.log(error)
          setAlert({
            showAlert: true,
            severity: 'error',
            message: 'Courier information creation failed!',
          })
        }
      } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your endpoints are not same. As in frontend, you are using '/courier' and in backend, you have only '/'.